# DiscordJs: Checking serverId when the bot is invited

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

*discord.js*
How do I know that my discord bot was invited by someone? And How do I Know The Server Id?

Comment: The `guildCreate` event emits the guild object, you can get the id from it. To know *who* invited the bot you'll need to check the audit logs of said guild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [guildCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event, then log the guild id somewhere by doing

```
guild.id
```

Then you can get the Guild ID

Comment: The problem is, @Elitezen's comment above has more information than your answer. Try to [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70430676/edit) and answer how OP can check if the bot is invited.